# Custom matcher for twitter's typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead

I am using twitter’s typeahead library: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js
I would like to know how to implement a custom matcher function.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples here on SO..

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypeahead%5D+matcher

Basically it's..

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    matcher: function(item) {
        // evaluate item variable and return true if the item was matched.
    }
})
```

Comment: I couldn't get matcher to be called unless I provided updater as well

Answer (score 2):

Is it just me or has matcher been removed from Typeahead.  Pity if it did.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a good sample on the twitter typeahead examples page. What you want to do requires a few extra lines:

```
var substringMatcher = function (strings) {
    return function findMatches(query, callback) {
        var matches;

        matches = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3'];

        callback(matches);
    };
};


var options = {};
var dataSet = {
    source: substringMatcher(states)
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead(options, dataSet);
```